# Django stack traces are awesome. How can I get one outside Django?

Tags: python, django

I guess The title says it all, bit I'll elaborate.

In non-Django programs (even in non-web projects) I would like to get stack traces with:

- Regular file and line number information, code of surrounding lines and scope identification (name of function and whatnot).
- Local scope variables (just their names and repr() would be great)

Is there a library? A visual python debugger I could provide a plugin for? How could I go about getting this stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the [`traceback` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html) from the Python documentation and the examples in it.

```
import sys, traceback

def run_user_code(envdir):
    source = raw_input(">>> ")
    try:
        exec source in envdir
    except:
        print "Exception in user code:"
        print '-'*60
        traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stdout)
        print '-'*60

envdir = {}
while 1:
    run_user_code(envdir)
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm rolling my own solution, and the traceback module is being invaluable to get all the data I need. It's the only way I found to get the filename of the module as well as the line number (so I could use linecache to read the code from it)